# jsp not recognizing a class even though I have imported in under proper packagename in eclipse

Tags: database, jsp, import, connection

[image: Screenshot: Jsp Page where I am importing the class]

[image: Screenshot : class which I am importing]

As you can see that it's not recognising the class `MySqlConnection`. Thus not allowing me to create its object. The class and package name is correct and its still not working. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo... Try to change from `MySqConnection` to `MySqlConnection`.